# An upper bound for a strictly increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let us start with a definition: A function $\alpha \colon \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is of class-$\mathcal{K}_\infty$ ($\alpha \in \mathcal{K}_\infty$) if it is continuous, zero at zero, strictly increasing and $\alpha(s) \to \infty$ as $s \to \infty$.

Let $\gamma , \varphi , \mu \in \mathcal{K}_\infty$ with $\mu (s) > s$ for all $s > 0$ and $c \in [0,1]$ be given. My question is:

Does there exist some $\overline{\gamma} \in \mathcal{K}_\infty$ such that
$$
\gamma(c \, \varphi \circ \mu (x)) \leq \overline{\gamma} (c \, \varphi (x))
$$
for all $x > 0$?

I was wondering if you help me with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there's such a function.

Let $c\neq 0.$ Define $\overline{\gamma}(x)=\gamma(f(x/c))$ where $f(x)=\varphi(\mu(\varphi^{-1}(x))).$

It works because $cf(x) \leq f(x)$ then $\gamma(cf(x)) \leq \gamma(f(x))$ which is in fact,

$$\gamma(c\varphi(\mu(\varphi^{-1}(x))))\leq \gamma(\varphi(\mu(\varphi^{-1}(x)))=\overline{\gamma}(cx)$$

and after changing the variable $x$ to $\varphi(x)$ the above ineqaulity will turn into

$$\gamma(c\varphi(\mu(x)))\leq \overline{\gamma}(c\varphi(x)).$$

**Note that** all $\mathcal{K}_\infty$ elements are *bijections*, so the change of variable doesn't do any harm.

Comment: I really appreciate it. You're very helpful.

Comment: @Navid You're welcome. You can now accept the answer by clicking the white tick to make it green and upvote it if you want.